# javascript to extract siblings, then send data to django

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django

I got something like

```
<tbody id="order_table">
       <tr class="list">
           <td data-status="old" class="food_name">food1</td>
           <td class="quantity">1</td>
           <td class="price">$10.00</td>
           <td><button type="button" class="btnIncrement btn"> <span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button></td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="list">
           <td data-status="old" class="food_name">food111</td>
           <td class="quantity">1</td>
           <td class="price">$10.00</td>
           <td><button type="button" class="btnIncrement btn"> <span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button></td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="list">
           <td data-status="new" class="food_name">food11</td>
           <td class="quantity">1</td>
           <td class="price">$10.00</td>
           <td><button type="button" class="btnIncrement btn"> <span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button></td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="list">
           <td data-status="new" class="food_name">food12</td>
           <td class="quantity">1</td>
           <td class="price">$10.00</td>
           <td><button type="button" class="btnIncrement btn"> <span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button></td>
       </tr>
 </tbody>
```

I would like to extract the food name, quantity and price of each `new` item and put them into array and finally send to django by ajax.. 
The order doesn't really matter
This is what I want.

```
[[food11, 1, 10.00], [food12, 1, 10.00]]
```

if no new item exists, it will return

```
[]
```

I can't really figure it out.. So I want some help. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newFood = [];

$('#order_table td.food_name').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('status') == 'new';
}).each(function() {
    newFood.push( [$(this).text(), $(this).siblings('.quantity').text(), $(this).siblings('.price').text()] );
});

$.ajax({
    // do you ajax
});
```